# Negated is_deeply() function in Test::More

Tags: unit-testing, perl, test-more

Test::More has `is_deeply()` and mentions in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More#Discouraged-comparison-functions) that it should be used instead of `eq_array()` or `eq_hash()` because it has better diagnostics, and it states *...They may be deprecated in future versions*

Now I'm replacing the use of `eq_...()` functions for `is_deeply()` but I run into a problem, there is no `is_not_deeply()` or such function, and I have a test like this:

```
ok (!eq_hash(\%h1, \%h2));
```

Is there an idiomatic alternative I can use to test deep *inequality*, preferably using Test::More?

Unlike `eq_hash()`, which just returns true or false and needs to be wrapped in `ok()`, `is_deeply()` itself is a test. So if you wrap it in "ok()" like below:

```
ok(!is_deeply(\%h1, \%h2));
```

There are now TWO tests, `is_deeply()` which is failing and `ok()`, which would pass!

Comment: The documentation says that they are equivalent, so a negation should be equivalent. Is there a reason you cannot do `ok ( !is_deeply(...)` )?

Comment: Because unlike eq_hash, is_deeply is a test itself. So if you wrap it in "ok()", there are TWO tests, is_deeply which is failing and ok, which would pass!

Comment: If this functionality is not available in `Test::More`, you could try use the [`isnt`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2::Tools::Compare) sub from [`Test2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2) instead

Comment: @MichielB You should mention that in your question. Put in the code and show how it is not working and why not. Then you may get answers. This question is vague.

Comment: @TLP I've clarified my question to explain this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this feature is not readily available with `Test::More`. Then I would recommend using [`Test2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2) instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test2::V0;

my %h1 = (a => [1,2,3], b=>"x");
my %h2 = (a => [1,2,3], b=>"x");

isnt (\%h1, \%h2, "Hashes are not equal" );
done_testing;
```